# Prove that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x)=\lim_{x \to \infty} f''(x)=0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

**Problem:** Prove that if $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ exists and $\lim_{x \to \infty} f''(x)$ exists, then $\lim_{x \to \infty} f''(x)=\lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x)=0$.

I just need help in proving that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x)$ exists. Hints would also be appreciated

Comment: you don't need to prove that, that is the basic assumption of this problem.

Comment: $f(x)=x$ do not have limit at $x\rightarrow +\infty$

Comment: I am assuming that the limit is finite.

Comment: @MoonKnight the problem just assume that the limits at infinite of $f(x)$ and $f''(x)$ exist but there is nothing about $f'(x)$.

Comment: A more general version is that if $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)$ exists and $f''(x)$ is bounded for all $x > a$ then $f'(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$. See http://math.stackexchange.com/q/730411/72031 The existence of limit of $f''(x)$ in this question ensures its boundedness for all $x$ greater than some number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By Taylor's theorem, for any $x $ there exists $x < \xi_x < x+1$ such that

$$f(x+1) = f(x) + f'(x) + f''(\xi_x)/2.$$

Then

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}f'(x) = \lim_{x \to \infty}f(x+1)- \lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)-  \lim_{x \to \infty}f''(\xi_x)/2 = -  \lim_{x \to \infty}f''(x)/2. $$