# $f$ and its $n$-th derivative are bounded imply the $i$-th derivative is bound for $1\leq i\leq n-1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a $n$ times continuously differentiable function such that $f$ and $f^{(n)}$ are bounded. Show that there is a constant $C$ such that
$$\big\|\,f^{\left(i\right)}\big\|_\infty=C\left(\big\|\;f\,\big\|_\infty+\big\|\,f^{\left(n\right)}\big\|_\infty\right)$$
for  $1\leq i\leq n-1$, where $\displaystyle\,\left\|\;f\,\right\|_\infty:=\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}} \left\lvert\, f\left(x\right)\right\rvert$ is the sup-norm.

I tried to use Taylor series with remainder, but cannot solve it. It seems that we need a theorem of Markoff which can be found [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1941-050-03/S0002-9947-1941-0005942-4/S0002-9947-1941-0005942-4.pdf). I cannot find the original paper in which Markoff proved the theorem.

Comment: Maybe one can use [Poincaré-Wirtinger inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincaré_inequality#The_Poincar.C3.A9-Wirtinger_inequality) to prove statement.

Comment: It is reminiscent of the Landau-Kolmogorov inequality: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%E2%80%93Kolmogorov_inequality

Comment: @Siminore: Actually, it is a consequence of that inequality. Simply because the right-hand side in that inequality can be estimated by $C(n,k,T) \max \{ \|f\|_\infty, \|f^{(n)}\|_\infty \} \leq C(n,k,T) (\|f\|_\infty + \|f^{(n)}\|_\infty)$.

Comment: see related http://math.stackexchange.com/q/730411/72031